# Convert List Items to Buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

So I am developing a POS (point of sale) software in WPF. I have all the product names & its prices etc. in a mysql database. I can easily retrieve the item names in a listview. But since this is for a POS, it needs to be buttons.

To test out the listview I followed the tutorial code here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/DataBinding10042007165025PM/DataBinding.aspx

How can I convert the menu item names (SQL query retrieves the list of names only) I retrieve from the database to buttons? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some pieces of your code, please?

Comment: I followed the simple tutorial here on:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/DataBinding10042007165025PM/DataBinding.aspx

Comment: Typically, you would use a `DataTemplate` for the `ListView.ItemTemplate` property, in which you e.g. bind the item name to the `Content` of a `Button` object. Lacking [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried along with a precise description of what that code does and how it's different from what you want, it's not possible to provide a good answer to your question. As stated, it's either too broad or a duplicate of one of the many WPF data templating questions already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand problem correctly you want the cell to look as a button
The easiest way is to provide CellTemplate on the column you want to look like a button

```
       <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Very close to what I was looking for. I can use this to do what I want to. Thanks!